# Merge/overlay data frames to replace only existing values in R

Tags: r, merge, dataframe, na

How can I merge the two data frames x and y so that existing values in y replace values in x? NAs in y must be ignored.

> x <- data.frame("A"=c(1,"ab",NA),"B"=c(12,1,5), "C"=c(5,5,10))
>
> y <- data.frame("A"=c(NA,NA,NA),"B"=c(60,NA,NA),  "C"=c(NA, 15,NA))

The expected result of the x-y-merge:

```
    A   B  C
1   1  60  5
2 "ab"  1 15
3  NA   5 10
```

x/y can include numeric and non-numeric values and the types should be preserved.

Comment: Use `x[!is.na(y)] <- y[!is.na(y)]`.

Comment: Also, be aware that vectors can only have one class (type). So in column `A`, the first entry will be converted to `"1"`.